# Find largest area using

Tags: c#

I need to find largest area with same numbers in 2D array. Example: {{**2** **2** 3}{1 **2** 3}{1 **2** 1}}

And mark it in new 2D array with same number for same area.

I will need to color the table with 3 colors, so i use between 1-3 in table[,]

I did test, but it doesn't work properly. ID just stacks too much on the same area.

Second edit: updated the code

```
public class Matrix
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Witdh { get; set; }
    public int[,] Table { get; set; }
    public int[,] Area { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int tempBiggestArea = 0;
    public int biggestArea { get; set; }
    public Matrix(int height, int witdh)
    {
        Table = GenerateTable(height, witdh);
        Height = height;
        Witdh = witdh;
        ID = 2;
        Area = new int[height,witdh];
    }
    public int[,] GenerateTable(int height, int witdh)
    {
        int[,] table = new int[height, witdh];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                table[i, j] = rnd.Next(3) + 1;
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
    public void Find(int x, int y, int color)
    {

        if (y < 0)
            y = Height - 1;

        if (x < 0)
            x = Witdh - 1;

        if (IsChanged(x, y))
            return;

        if (Area[x, y] == 0)
        {
            if (color > 3)
                color = 1;

            if (Table[x, y] == color)
            {
                Area[x, y] = ID;
                tempBiggestArea++;
                Find(x, y - 1, color);
                Find(x - 1, y, color);
                ID++;
            }
        }
        if (tempBiggestArea > biggestArea)
            biggestArea = tempBiggestArea;
        tempBiggestArea = 0;
        Find(x, y, color + 1);
    }
    public bool IsChanged(int i, int j)
    {
        return Area[i, j] != 0;
    }
```

Comment: From the sample code it's not very clear how you're trying to do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to go thruoghout int[,] Table with random generated numbers between 1 and 3 with color that is given when calling( i calling method with color == 1, x and y is Table.GetLenght(0) and Table.GetLenght(1)). If first number from table is equal to 1 then I add ID (which is equal to 2 at the start) to same position in new 2D array called area. If its not equal to that, then i call same method, just color + 1.

Comment: I can't help but feel like you might be overcomplicating things. I'd recommend you look into "Blob Detection".

Comment: I must use recursion, that's why it's so complicated